# Sliding content script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote this script to slide the content over on clicking the span.

I need to give the top menu a different background color then the body so need to contain it with the divs `"bblock1"` "container" `"bodymainMAX"`. on do so the script no longer can refer to the next div to slide as its 3 div's away.

works fine if i leave the `"tabbed_content"` and `"slide_content"` together.

Is there any function that i can use to resolve this? Thank you.

**WORKING**:

```
<div class="bblock1" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMax">
    <div class='tabbed_content'>
        <div class='tabs'>
            <div class='moving_bg'>&nbsp;</div>
            <span class='tab_item'>features</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>Addons</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>Pricing</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>FAQ's</span>
        </div>
        <div class='slide_content'>                        
            <ul class='tabslider'>
                <li>aaaaajjjjmmmmmmmmmmmma</li>
                <li>Bbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
                <li>Ccccccccccccc</li>
                <li>Ddddddddddddd</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**DOESNT WORK:**

```
<div class="bblock1" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMax">
    <div class='tabbed_content'>
        <div class='tabs'>
            <div class='moving_bg'>&nbsp;</div>
            <span class='tab_item'>features</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>Addons</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>Pricing</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>FAQ's</span>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bblock3" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMax">
        <div class='slide_content'>                        
            <ul class='tabslider'>
                <li>aaaaajjjjmmmmmmmmmmmma</li>
                <li>Bbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
                <li>Ccccccccccccc</li>
                <li>Ddddddddddddd</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().find(".moving_bg").stop().animate({
                left: $this.position()['left']
            }, { duration: 300 });
    });
var TabbedContent = {
    current: {i:null, obj:null},
    init: function() {
        $(".tab_item").click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            TabbedContent.slideContent($this);
        });
        TabbedContent.current.i = 0;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $(".tabslider li").eq(0);
    },
    slideContent: function($obj) {
        var $container = $obj.cloest(".tabbed_content");
        var $tabslider = $container.find(".tabslider");
        var i = $obj.index() - 1;
        var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
        $new = $lis.eq(i);
        if(i === TabbedContent.current.i) {
            return;
        }
        $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent.current.obj)).show();
        var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        $tabslider.stop().css({
            marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
        }, 1200);
        TabbedContent.current.i = i;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $new;
    }
}
TabbedContent.init();
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/r73b14y5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is because you unwrap your tabs content from tabbed_content container. Here is updated slideContent function:

```
slideContent: function($obj) {
    var $container = $obj.closest(".tabbed_content"),        
        $contentContainer = $('.bodymainMax'),
          $tabslider = $contentContainer.find(".tabslider");
    var i = $obj.index() - 1;
    var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
    $new = $lis.eq(i);
    if(i === TabbedContent.current.i) {
        return;
    }
    $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent.current.obj)).show();
    var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
    var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
    $tabslider.stop().css({
        marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
    }).animate({
        marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
    }, 1200);
    TabbedContent.current.i = i;
    TabbedContent.current.obj = $new;
}
```

And working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kison/r73b14y5/1/)

Comment: Thats it perfect. thank you. need to re target the element.